# AFHTTPRequestOperation doesn't work after stand by mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

I am developing a app which upload multiple files.
For uploading, I use `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. It successfully works, But If I lock and after it unlock the screen,then It stop uploading files.

My code for upload file is here

```
NSUserDefaults *defaultUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *userId = [defaultUser stringForKey:@"UserId"];

AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",UploadURL,userId]]];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData: data name:@"f" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_image.jpeg",rand()] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {}];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
        if(error.code == -1001){
        UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                          message:@"The request timed out." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [myAlert show];
        }
    }];


[operation start];
```

Can anyone give me suggestion for handle this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: It's something to do with setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler but I'm not 100% sure where that code has to go

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164755/1702413

Comment: @TonyMkenu that's for NSURL connection, not AFNetworking?

Comment: @Nick yes (just un example), but .. As of AFNetworking 1.0RC1, AFURLConnectionOperation has a setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method that can be used to have operations continue when an app is dismissed and enters the background https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ

Comment: @Nick http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Comment: @TonyMkenu thanks for the link, I'm using it in a faux singleton (as suggested on the github page), and just can't work out how to apply that method

Answer (score 2):

(1) Add this code:

```
[operation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    // Handle iOS shutting you down (possibly make a note of where you
    // stopped so you can resume later)
}];
```

(2) Change this line:

```
[operation start];
```

to

```
[client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

(3) Keep a strong reference to your AFHTTPClient (this is typically done for AFHTTPClient with the singleton pattern) so that your operations don't get deallocated

Comment: setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler is not called, I need some help on this