# How to continue in the background a connection started with NSURLConnection in the foreground?

Tags: ios, background, nsurlconnection

I tried the answer of this question

[How can a connection started with NSURLConnection while in the foreground be continued in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163960/how-can-a-connection-started-with-nsurlconnection-while-in-the-foreground-be-con)

And works like a charm! but **only if device is connected** to my iMac... 
Once I disconnect my iOS device the app runs for 3 minutes more in background and then the app starts again, this not happens if the iOS device is connected.
Why is happening this? Is there any way to continue the upload in the background until the 10 minutes like it must be?

I'm not implementing this code

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Handle the error
    ...
    //this line
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskID];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // Save the downloaded data
    ...
    //and this line
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskID];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection wasn't intended to be used when your app isn't running.  Use an upload task in an NSURLSession background session, and it will work as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that the app runs for 3 minutes because is the time that the app can be running in background until iOS sends the app to sleep, is there any tutorial or guide to change NSURLConnection to NSURLSession?