# Continue background task after 3 minutes

Tags: ios, background, nsurlconnection

I tried the answer of this question

[How can a connection started with NSURLConnection while in the foreground be continued in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163960/how-can-a-connection-started-with-nsurlconnection-while-in-the-foreground-be-con)

And works like a charm! but **only for 3 minutes** in background, then iOS sends the app to sleep, Im trying to upload n videos and 3 minutes is not enought to send all data, I also readed that I can change my NSURLConnection to NSURLSession but I have no idea how to start that or how much time it takes.

Is there a way to keep background task alive after 3 minutes and until upload ends?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to keep background task alive after 3 minutes and until upload ends?

No, there isn't. On-going background execution is limited to very narrow purposes (e.g. playing music, VOIP apps, navigation apps, etc.). All of this is outlined in the [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) section of the *App Programming Guide for iOS.*

> I also [read] that I can change my `NSURLConnection` to `NSURLSession` but I have no idea how to start that or how much time it takes.

Yes, this is correct. If you want network request to continue for more than a few minutes after the app enters background, you should use `NSURLSession` with a background `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. See [Downloading Content in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) in the *App Programming Guide for iOS* for more information. See WWDC 2013 [What's New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/705/) for introduction to `NSURLSession`, including a demonstration on how to do background session.

I'd suggest you tackle this in two steps: First, convert to `NSURLSession`, and second, enable background `NSURLSession` operation. I think you'll find this first step is pretty easy. All of the concepts are very familiar. The only trick is that `NSURLSession` has two types of interfaces, delegate-protocol pattern and completion handlers. If you plan on using this for background operation later, you'll want to stick with the delegate-protocol pattern because the simpler completion handler pattern is not compatible with background sessions. And you'll want to use the upload task method that uploads from a file (don't use the stream-based rendition).

This second step, enabling background operation, isn't hard, but it can be tricky, though, simply because it involves a few new little details that we haven't had to worry about in the past (e.g. the app delegate code to capture (and later call) the completion handler for background sessions). Also, when you start debugging background session code, it can be disorienting to have requests initiated by one debugging session to show up in the next debugging session (hey, they're background sessions that are supposed to keep running when your app is terminated, after all). It's not a problem, but can be a bit disorienting.

Comment: Appreciate  for your input. As `UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining` gives 180 seconds max. Can't we extend <in May 2018>? or is there another way to run the services/func in background.

Comment: In general, no. There are tons of specific solutions, e.g., background `URLSession`, background fetch, push notifications, significant change location service, background location services, etc., so if you specify what legitimate need you have for on going background operation, we might be able to help you. But the essential design concern (that Apple provides only just a few, very specific mechanisms for on-going background operation) is driven by the fact that unbridled background operation by each and every app on our phones would quickly crush our batteries, even in 2018.